# Problemas con bucle for al renderizar input checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp

Tengo el siguiente problema al momento de renderizar unos input `checkbox`, pasa que recorro con un bucle `for` con un modelo de tipo `List<>` como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.MiModeloList.Count(); i++)
{
    if (Model.MiModeloList[i].Num == 1 || Model.MiModeloList[i].Num == 2 || Model.MiModeloList[i].Num == 3)
    {
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 li">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MiModeloList[i].Num)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MiModeloList[i].Nom)
            <label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MiModeloList[i].IsSelected)
                <span class="title">@Model.MiModeloList[i].Nom</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Y se renderizan los inputs que necesito, pero al momento de dar `f5` en la pagina se vuelven a renderizar los mismos inputs aparte de los que ya había renderizado por primera vez, haciendo que cada vez que actualizo la pagina me cree los mismo inputs nuevamente.

¿Como puedo evitar esto? ¿Servirá con un `foreach`?` Para que solo una vez me renderize los inputs en la vista y al darle actualizar en la pagina no me renderize los mismos inputs haciendo que en vez de 3 termine teniendo n inputs...

En el controlador de acción lo único que hago es retornar lo que retorna este método. El método de acción es GET

```
private static MiModelo model = new MiModelo();

    private static MiModelo MiMetodo()
    {
        model.MiModeloList.Add(new MiModelo.Modelo() { Cod = (int)Enums.Files.DepositoPlazo, Nom = Enums.File.DepositoPlazo.GetDescription() });
        model.MiModeloList.Add(new MiModelo.Modelo() { Cod = (int)Enums.Files.AhorroEducacion, Nom = Enums.File.AhorroEducacion.GetDescription() });
        return model;
    }
```

Comment: Coloca todo el código del controlador, esta es la primera vez que veo un caso así.

Comment: Actualice la pregunta.

Comment: con razón, tienes ese "modelo" estático y en cada llamada a Mi Modelo MiMetodo() vas a terminar agregando más y más elementos... Te recomiendo que le des play a este workshop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Saludos :D